# GET POST requests in node js

Tags: node.js

Hi friends I'm new in MERN application build I want to know that How we can handle requests in nodeJs and connect mongoose to the database. Please help me out.

Comment: Find nearly any tutorial on building a web server in nodejs and it will show you how to handle requests.  Many people use the Express library to make it very simple.  You really ought to find a tutorial, work through it and then come back here and ask questions if/when you get stuck.  This shouldn't be the first place you go to find tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the library [Express.js](https://expressjs.com/), but you could also use another one if you want to.

Here's an example for how this could look like in Express:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); // necessary for req.body

app.post('login', function(req, res){
   let data = req.body;
   // do something..
   res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Comment: The questioner also mentioned `mongoose`, haha. @_@

Comment: mongoose is not a part of nodejs

Comment: They either added that later, or I'm stupid @GyuHyeonChoi